# Unable to use on click function on list element within modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make list elements in a bootstrap modal clickable.
My modal has the ID: `crModal`, My list has the id `crtList` and my elements have the class `CRT`.

I am using this script to activate a function when an element is clicked

```
$("#crtList").on("click", "li.CRT", function(event){
    alert("It worked")
});
```

For some reason this script isn't activating when I click an element of the list within the modal

Comment: you don't need 2nd argument, i.e. `"li.CRT"`. instead give it an appropriate id link in the prefix.

Comment: You're correct to use a delegated event handler, however my guess is that `#crtList` does not exist when the DOM loads, hence your code won't work. To test this change `$('#crtList')` to `$(document)` and try again.

Comment: Also note that JS is case-sensitive, so `Alert()` needs to be `alert()`, otherwise you'll get an error

Comment: Excellent. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that you need to use a delegated event handler as the modal is dynamically created in the page. However the event needs to be bound to an element that exists in the DOM when the page loads. Given that you state `#crtList` is part of the modal this would seem to not be the case.

To fix this you can change `$('#crtList')` to `$(document)` to get the code working:

```
$(document).on("click", "li.CRT", function(event){
  console.log("It worked")
});
```